# how to create openstreetmap offline ios map

Tags: iphone, ios, mapping

Dose anyone have any good tutorials or suggestions on how to create an offline map app of a specific area, using the openstreetmaps or something similar? This topic is so hard to find anything out about t I was hoping someone here might have an idea or has tried it before.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hello hurk Nburks how did u achieve this..? can u guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but check out [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/mobile/), which has offline map support.

Comment: Cheers dude.. I have seen this in the past.. I was hoping to get by doing something for free.. but I think this is alot more polished than anything I can create and the app I would like to build will benefit from it.. so I think I am going to take the plunge and go with this... thanks for the reminder. :)